# How do I create a data.table by combining programatically named vectors?

Tags: r, data.table

I have data similar to this:

```
number_of_runs <- 4
r1 <- c(1,2,3)
r2 <- c(4,5,6)
r3 <- c(7,8,9)
r4 <- c(10,11,12)
```

I regularly have differing numbers of runs (saved as three numbers in a vector named r1 for first run, r2 for second run, etc.).  I would like to combine these vectors into a `data.table` but since the number of runs varies, I need to do this programatically.

Below works perfectly for a set number of runs outputting `dt` exactly as I need it:

```
dt <- data.table(r1,r2,r3,r4)
```

I need something similar to this below but that actually works:

```
dt <- data.table(c(paste0("r", 1:number_of_runs)))
```

So, if there are 3 runs, it will output a data.table like `data.table(r1,r2,r3)` and if there are 4 runs, it will output a data.table like `data.table(r1,r2,r3,r4)` and so on.

I am using `data.table` version 1.10.4 on a Windows 7 machine.  I appreciate your ideas on this.

Comment: Where did the 4 `r*` vectors come from? Building different variables with related information isn't the best way to do things. Those should probably be in a list which makes things much easier to work with. But the problem you are having is that you can't replace symbols (things without quotes) with character values (which is what `paste0()` returns).

Comment: @MrFlick I am not wedded to using vectors for the 4 `r*`.  How would you suggest creating the 4 `r*` in a list to solve this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: Well, how did you create them in the first place? Did you run some function 4 times? Something like `r <- replicate(4, roll())` might work. Or just using those values literally, `r <- list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9), c(10,11,12))`. Then you can get them with `r[[1]]` , `r[[2]]`, etc. And can use `do.call("data.table", r)` to but them in a data.table.

Comment: Note that you can skip the list and just call r <- data.table(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9), c(10,11,12)).

Comment: Binding rows makes a lot more sense here, I think.

Comment: @MrFlick Each of the 4 `r*` were created earlier in my code as Mean, Median, Standard Deviation of each run of data.

Comment: @MrFlick I am trying to create a summary `data.table` that will have the Mean, Median, StDev for each run of data performed.  Sometimes there will be 30 runs, sometimes there will be 200 runs.  That's why I am trying to figure out a way to do this programatically.  Thanks.

Comment: @Frank What do you mean by "Binding rows makes a lot more sense"?  How would you apply that to the current problem?

Comment: I mean that each run should be a row in your result. Starting from MrFlick's `r` list: `rbindlist(lapply(r, function(x) as.data.table(as.list(x))))`. You are currently putting each run in its own column, which is counterproductive in R..

Comment: @Frank Great thanks.  I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MrFlick noted, it would be much simpler if the `r*` vectors were stored in a better format. For example, they could be put directly into a data.table. Or, if they were in a list called say `rList`, then your answer would simply be to use `as.data.table(rList)`. So really you need to re-evaluate how you have created these variables. Please share that code with us!

For completeness, though, there is a way to do exactly what you have asked: to start from a character vector of variables, and combine the variables with those names in the current environment into a `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
# say we must start with these vectors flaoting around the global environment
r1 <- c(1,2,3)
r2 <- c(4,5,6)
r3 <- c(7,8,9)
r4 <- c(10,11,12)
number_of_runs <- 4

# collect their names in a character vector as you have done:
rNames <- paste0("r", 1:number_of_runs)
# collapse them into one string
rNamesCollapsed <- paste(rNames, collapse = ", ")
# form the command we need to switch to create the data.table, still as a character vector:
commandString <- paste0("data.table(", rNamesCollapsed , ")")
# parse the character vector command into an R expression:
commandExpr <- parse(text = commandString)
# evaluate the expression to get the data.table:
dt <- eval(commandExpr )
```

**I don't reccommend you proceed this way, I just wanted to include this example to help you appreciate the different between expressions and character vectors, and thus why your approach did not work.**

Obviously all of that code can be shortened, but I wanted to break down what was going on. As @Roland suggested, a shorter and better way is to use `mget`, which directly searches for variables with given names and returns them in an appropriately named list.

```
# collect their names in a character vector as you have done:
rNames <- paste0("r", 1:number_of_runs)
# search the environment for objects with those names, and put them into a list:
rList <- mget(rNames)
# convert the list to a data.table:
dt <- as.data.table(rList)
```

Comment: Downvoting for evaluating parsed text. If you have such vectors use mget to collect them into a list and proceed from there.

Comment: I don't see where they are asking for parsing text and you certainly shouldn't suggest it.

Comment: They attempted to do it in this line: `dt <- data.table(c(paste0("r", 1:number_of_runs))). ` And in no way did I suggest it -- see my bolded disclaimer. You could also use `mget`, but I wanted to demonstrate this method for learning's sake. I thought it might spark them to consider why their solution did not work.

Comment: If you think that any references `parse` and `eval` should be removed, feel free to improve my answer by deleting that solution.

Comment: @mb7744 Thanks so much for your work on this.  Because it was required to ultimately output this info in a wide format, your suggestions regarding `mget` worked perfectly.  Here's what I ended up using and it performed exactly as required: **`dt <- as.data.table(mget(paste0("r", 1:number_of_runs)))`**.  Perhaps, according to other comments, it is not the most efficient but it worked great for this situation.